# await is not working in getServerSideProps nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Nextjs and I want to get data from getServerSideProps . I wrote a function (handler) to get the data and I used to await in async function,

```
export async function getServerSideProps({req, res}){
   
    const myCookie = await parseCookies(req);
    if(!myCookie.user){
        return {
            redirect:{
                destination:'/login'
            }
            
        }
    }
    /////////////////////////////////
    const myData = await handler(myCookie.user);
    console.log('getData getData' , myData);


    return {
        props : {
            files: myData ,
        },
    }
};
```

```
import User from '../../../models/UserModel';
import Files from '../../../models/FileModel';
import dbConnec from '../../../utils/dbConnect';
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');

dbConnec();

export async function handler(authorization) {
    const token = authorization;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "MySuperSecret");
    var id = decoded.userId;
    return Files.find({user : id }).exec((err, filesUser) => {
     if(err){
        console.log('datadatadatadata2222222222222');
        return [];
     }else{
        console.log('datadatadatadata' , filesUser);
        return filesUser;
     }
   });
};
```

but first I run the next line which is the console("getData getData")  and then the function consoles are printed("datadatadatadata").And no data will be returned, please help us.

Comment: I would not connect to your DB as a side effect of importing a module.